# How to remove bullets from Unordered list nested in Div's?

Tags: html, css, list, bullet

I don't see why my code isn't working. I want to remove the bullets on my ul anchors. but "ul {list-style: none;} isn't working.

Here's my code:

```
<div class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="logo">
        <!-- <a href="/">Logo</a> -->
    </div>
    <div class="main-page-links">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">MENU</a></li>
            <li><a href="">WEEKLY EVENTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="">FILLER</a></li>
            <li><a href="">FILLER</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery">
        <img src="" alt="image galleries">
    </div>

</div>
```

And here's the Css:

```
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;}

body{
    height: 100%;
}

.nav-wrapper{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1);
    grid-template-rows: 8;

height: 100px;
width: 900px;}

ul { list-style: none;}  /* I thought this would do it */
```

Comment: I don't see no bullets!, this must be a part of a greater code, and the bullets may come from there..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe your browser is cached, try using <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> on the page you are using, your code is fine here

```css
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;}

body{
    height: 100%;
}

.nav-wrapper{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1);
    grid-template-rows: 8;

height: 100px;
width: 900px;}

ul { list-style: none;}
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="logo">
        <!-- <a href="/">Logo</a> -->
    </div>
    <div class="main-page-links">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">MENU</a></li>
            <li><a href="">WEEKLY EVENTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="">FILLER</a></li>
            <li><a href="">FILLER</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery">
        <img src="" alt="image galleries">
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Idk I did this already, didn't change a thing unfortunately, but thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I tried list-style: none, no bullets show.

```css
*{
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
box-sizing: border-box;}

body{
    height: 100%;
}

.nav-wrapper{
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1);
    grid-template-rows: 8;

height: 100px;
width: 900px;}

ul { list-style: none;}  /* I thought this would do it */
```

```html
<div class="nav-wrapper">
    <div class="logo">
        <!-- <a href="/">Logo</a> -->
    </div>
    <div class="main-page-links">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="">MENU</a></li>
            <li><a href="">WEEKLY EVENTS</a></li>
            <li><a href="">FILLER</a></li>
            <li><a href="">FILLER</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div class="gallery">
        <img src="" alt="image galleries">
    </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Cause I ran it in CodePen an the bullets were hidden, but in firefox and chrome they're still there....

Answer (score 0):

try executing it with

list-style-type: none;

it should work perfectly.